# Springboot Autowire new Object in abstract class

Tags: java, spring-boot, autowired

I have a question on java:

take this example code

```
    public abstract class abstractClass {
        MyClass obj;

        public void init(Object obj) {
            this.obj = obj;
            do();
        }

        protected abstract void do();

    }

    @Component
    public class A implements abstractClass {

        @override
        protected void do() {
            this.obj.doThing();
        }
    }

    @Component
    public class TheClassIamNow {
        @Autowire
        private A aClass;

        public void iAmHereInTheCode() {

            MyClass obj = new MyClass();
            aClass.init(obj);

        }
    }
```

following this example I get a `NullPointerException` on `obj` that is inside the abstract class on the class `A` whe I try to access `obj`

In this example `Object` of course cannot be autowired cause it's not a component and comes from  another library where i'm forced to use the `new MyClass()`

I was wondering if there was a way to achieve this

Comment: I don't understand if you said "Class A is not a component" but I see on your question it is marked as `component`.

Comment: Jonathan
The class `A` is a component indeed but it's `MyClass` that is not a component and becomes null when used inside `A`

Comment: OK, @nautilor looks weird based what you described, so could you please add `logs` and full `stacktrace` on this error? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

TheClassIamNow must also be annotated as a Component to have spring autowire it's variables.

Comment: My bad, `TheClassIamNow` is a component, I forgot to write it

Answer (score 0):

class A **extends** abstractClass.  You have implements which is for interfaces.